# Is it possible to use dotnet build to output all assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know I can set CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies to true in the project file, to enforce all assemblies to to be copied to the output directory.
However, is it possibly to specify this option in the dotnet build command?

Comment: I did use `--runtime linux-x64` in desperation  when I had missing assemblies but I doubt it that has the same functional meaning as CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies. For me the `--runtime` option solved my assembly problem. YMMV. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Comment: Why, for what type of project? `dotnet build` already does, for executables, web site projects and  unit tests. `dotnet publish` will package even runtime libraries. *Class libary projects* don't because they don't need it - libraries aren't executed directly. *Packages* on the other hand are a different business